# How do a check if something is in an integer that is in a list

Tags: python

This is some of my code: (I defined the variables in the list "crates" by choosing a random number for each of them by the way)

```
crates = [one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve, thirteen, fourteen, fifteen, sixteen, seventeen, eighteen, nineteen, twenty, twentyone, twentytwo, twentythree, twentyfour, twentyfive, twentysix]

choicecrate = int(input("Which crate do you think is your lucky crate? "))

#insert figuring out if 'choicecrate' is 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. then removing it from the list
```

I'm trying to check if the number the user inputted is the number writing of the variables in the list "crates". How do I do this? For example, the person inputs the number 17, I need to make the computer figure out that "17" is seventeen, then remove it from the list. How do I do this? I also need to keep 'choicecrate' as an integer. This may be an easy question, but I'm a beginner.

Comment: `Wait. "one", "two", ... "twentysix" are all undefined.`

Comment: Does `crates` contain strings or ints?  The code as you've written it won't work because `one` isn't defined.  Did you mean `1` or `"one"`?

Answer (score 1):

Since the list is in sequence, one, two, three etc. You can simply check if the number the user entered is valid by comparing it to the length of the list.

```
crates = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "twentyone", "twentytwo", "twentythree", "twentyfour", "twentyfive", "twentysix"]

choicecrate = int(input("Which crate do you think is your lucky crate? "))

if 1 <= choicecrate <= len(crates):
    print("Input is in the list!")
```

Comment: Good, but note that this answers only half of the question.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
crates = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen", "twenty", "twentyone", "twentytwo", "twentythree", "twentyfour", "twentyfive", "twentysix"]
keys = list(range(1,27))
dic = dict(zip(keys,crates))
for _ in range(3):
    choicecrate = int(input("Which crate do you think is your lucky crate? "))
    if choicecrate in dic.keys():
        print("The choicecrate in crates!")
        del dic[choicecrate]
    else:
        print("The choicecrate not in crates!")
```

result:

```
Which crate do you think is your lucky crate? 0
The choicecrate not in crates!
Which crate do you think is your lucky crate? 17
The choicecrate in crates!
Which crate do you think is your lucky crate? 17
The choicecrate not in crates!
```

Comment: I may have not formatted the question correctly. I meant to say that 1-26 in the list are variables, not strings. I need to find a way to link the variable seventeen to the input "17".